# Focus textbox onload with mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a login-page and would like the "Username" textbox focus when page loads.

How is that done best using MVC? Some script or jquery or something?

/M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('myTextBox').focus();">
```

or in jquery

```
$(function() { $('#myTextbox').focus(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

via Jquery

```
$(function() {
  $("#Username").focus();
});
```